# Table Column too high

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [Datatables](http://datatables.net), a jQuery plugin for creating custom tables. I am trying to create now a table with many columns, at least one of them containing a lot of text. The problem is that the column with long text is not created wider, but taller, making the table more difficult for the user to read.

How can I make the text column wider and less higher?

Here is a screenshot with my problem:

[image]

Here is my problem visible:

http://live.datatables.net/ujudij/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you may consider to use css text-overflow property: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/ and in conjunction with a tooltip of the cell which has a long text.

Comment: This only works if the browser supports CSS3, but I will consider the tooltip idea.

Comment: @Dragos in order to use this you'd have to set a fixed width and height anyway (unless these are already set by the plugin). However, doing so, and setting `overflow: hidden;` will work in browsers that do not support `text-overflow: ellipsis`. `overflow` will work like `text-overflow` except it will not automatically add the ellipsis. Then, you could have the `td` fully visible on hover, or by some other means to accommodate. This is probably your best option unless you manually truncate the data and add the ellipsis yourself.

Comment: This is the best solution so far. Other users have also suggested using a tooltip(maybe the jQuery plugin qTip) and elaborated on this idea, but your answer came first, so I will offer you the bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can check the length of text for each td after datatable render is complete. If the text length exceeds you defined limit, you can then set a larger width for that table cell i.e td. This way you can widen any cell that exceeds your desired height even if you don't know where is it in the table

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
    "sScrollX":"100%",
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {

        $('#example tr').each(function(i){
           $('td', this).each(function(j){
               // get length of text
               var l = $(this).text().length;
               // set larger width if text length is greater than 300 characters
               if(l > 300){
                   $(this).width(400);
               }
           });
        });
    }
  });
});
```

[See this code demo here](http://live.datatables.net/icesux/15/edit#preview)

You can also use cell height using **var l = $(this).height();** but i don't think that will provide you correct result, because before adjusting width other cells in same row which may not have large texts also have same height, so their width property will also be changed using this, which is not correct for your situation, i guess

Although I think a better idea would be to trim the text to limit, add a "more" link and show full text using some plugin like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Comment: The solution you suggested is not working. By changing the td's width I ruin the whole table: the header does no longer match it's content. This is visible in your demo as well. I will consider though your other suggestion and might use qTip.

Comment: I just made an example with one cell, you can always update header and footer cell element at index "j" with your width to fix it. But I think it is better not bring that much complexity for it, go for trimming and tooltip solutions

Answer (score 4):

I've written a small jQuery plugin to limit text lines of an element, hope this can help.

```
/** 
* Binaray search with callback
*/
function bisearch(left, right, search, getter){
    var pos, result;
    if (typeof getter !== "function") {
        getter = function (x) {
            return x;
        };
    }

    while (left <= right) {
        pos = (left + right) / 2 | 0;
        result = getter(pos);

        if (result < search) {
            left = pos + 1;
        }
        else if (result > search) {
            right = pos - 1;
        }
        else {
            return pos;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

;(function($){
    var getLineHeight = function(el) {
        var self = el,
            $self = $(self),
            content = $self.html(),
            lineHeight;

        if (typeof $self.attr("style") !== "undefined") {
            orgStyleAttr = $self.attr("style");             
        }

        $self.html("&nbsp;").css("min-height", "0px");
        lineHeight = $self.height();

        $self.html(content);

        if (typeof orgStyleAttr !== "undefined") {
            $self.attr("style", orgStyleAttr);
        } else {
            $self.removeAttr("style");
        }
        return lineHeight;
    }
    $.fn.limitLines = function(maxLines){
        $(this).each(function(){
            var self = this,
                $self = $(self),
                content = $self.html(),
                height = $self.height(),
                lineHeight = getLineHeight($self),
                maxHeight = lineHeight * maxLines;

            if (Math.floor(height/lineHeight) <= maxLines) 
                return;

            // this search will stop when the text meet the line count,
            // but the last line will be of any length
            var middleOfLastLine = bisearch(0, content.length, maxLines, function (n){
                $self.html(content.substring(0, n));
                return Math.floor($self.height() / lineHeight); 
            });

            // search for position from current to current plus one more line, 
            // until we find the excact position(p) to stop,
            // where if one more letter was added, 
            // there will be a new line 
            var endOfLastLine = bisearch(middleOfLastLine, content.length, maxLines + .5, function (n){
                $self.html(content.substring(0, n - 3) + '...');
                var before = Math.floor($self.height() / lineHeight);

                $self.html(content.substring(0, n - 2) + '...');
                var after = Math.floor($self.height() / lineHeight);

                return (before + after) / 2;
            });
            $self.html(content.substring(0, endOfLastLine -3) + '...');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I've rewritten the code with binary search, this version works faster. A new getLineHeight() function is also added.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `aoColumnDefs` which allows you to target specific columns by title or number, and set the width of the desired columns by using the plug-in's native `sWidth` property:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var data = $('#example').dataTable({
   "sScrollX":"100%",
   "aoColumnDefs": [
   { "sWidth": "1500px", "aTargets": [5] } // this will target the 6th column (the first being 0) 
]
});

});
```

[a working example](http://live.datatables.net/ujudij/6)

[documentation](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns)

If you don't know in advance which columns to target you can always get the `length` of the string in each cell, and act accordingly. that is, if the length exceeds a certain no. of chars, you add the column number to an array, later passed to `aTargets`

Answer (score 2):

You can enlarge a column as you wish, I used 70% but you can also use pixels like 400px

http://live.datatables.net/ajemid/4/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "sScrollX":"100%",
     "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "sWidth": "70%", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ]
  });
} );
```

"aTargets": [ 0 ] is for the first column, 1 for the second, etc..

For limiting the text, you could apply css properties like max-height:200px; and overflow:hidden; you could also apply a vertical gradient (transparent to white) over the bottom of the cell to give a nice fading-to-white effect to the long cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#example').dataTable( {
"bAutoWidth": false
} );
} );
```

Later set `width` for  `<td>` inside your table.

Comment: setting `bAutoWidth` to false does not solve my issue. What is more, setting a different width to my `<td>s` makes the content of the table get out of sync with the column headers. It basically makes the table unusable. Do you happen to have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is wrap anything that goes into the table with a `nobr` html tag. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it will work, and you can use CSS to limit your cell widths and set your overflows. I cloned your example [here](http://live.datatables.net/uzutiv/2).

Reading through the DataTables documentation, the manual solution might only work if you're calling `datatable()` on an existing DOM element. If you want to do this while loading data from an array or from an AJAX source, you might have to programmatically wrap the data in each table cell with `nobr` tags using jQuery. The nice thing about this is that you can have more control over what you decide to nowrap.

The DataTables API provides [pre-init](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_pre_init.html) or the [post-init](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_post_init.html) API calls - you can tie a callback to a jQuery function that iterates through all the TDs in the table and wraps the contents in `nobr` tags.

I hope this made sense. Best of luck!

Comment: It makes sense what you are saying. The same could be accomplished with `white-space:nowrap`. The problem here is that I get a very long column, thus replacing a problem with another. If I add an `overflow:auto`, controlling the width as you suggested, I will get a scrollable table with scrollable cells - scrollception :D. It feels a bit weird. Do you have any other suggestion on how should I avoid creating further scrolls?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it scrollbars automatically appear on oversized data

```
<style>
.box{width:250;height:75;overflow:auto}
</style>

<div class="box" >your data here will only have a scrollbar if it overflows your predefined height width parameters</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify your own width for each column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "sScrollX":"100%",
    "aoColumns": [
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" },
      { "sWidth": "30%" }
    ]
  });
} );
```

Comment: This does not change anything. It is probably because the sum of all sWidths is greater than 100% and that is why the specification is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

your solution is the `%`

change the name of this td class from `odd gradeA` to `what_ever` and add this

```
    width: 80%;
```

of course you can play with it how much you want .

or change this

```
 <tr class="odd gradeA"> //of the long text
```

to

```
  <tr style="width: 80%">
```

and all other `td`s will be triggered 
so you can also make the same thing to other `td`s how much u like by `%`
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my view you should limit the out put from your script on server side, It will create better visual effect, but also saves some bandwidth, and will reduce page load

Answer (score 0):

Improvising @Burhan's reply: you can limit the characters directly displayed in the cell and add that to the title of the cell so it will create a tooltip kind of effect (== qTip??)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
    "sScrollX":"100%",
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {

        $('#example tr').each(function(i){
           $('td', this).each(function(j){
               // get length of text
               var l = $(this).text().length;
               var limit = 200;
               // set larger width if text length is greater than 300 characters
               if(l > limit){
                   $(this).attr('title',$(this).text())
                          .text($(this).text().substr(0,limit));
               }
           });
        });
    }
  });
});
```

change limit variable to whatever is confortable to you.........